# ３３行目のvalueにエラーが出ます→Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value'

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
        // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 35.665751, longitude: 139.728687, zoom: 6.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.frame, camera: camera)
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)

        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 35.665751, longitude: 139.728687)
        marker.title = "六本木"
        marker.snippet = "東京都港区六本木７丁目４−１"
        marker.map = mapView

        AF.request("https://map.yahooapis.jp/search/local/V1/localSearch?cid=d8a23e9e64a4c817227ab09858bc1330&lat=35.662654694078626&lon=139.73135330250383&dist=2&query=%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3&appid=dj00aiZpPWdzNkFwb2NZRWxBbiZzPWNvbnN1bWVyc2VjcmV0Jng9MjY-&output=json").responseJSON { response in

            if let jsonObject = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(jsonObject)
                let features = json["Feature"]
                // If json is .Dictionary
                for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
                   // Do something you want
                    let name = subJson["Name"].stringValue
                    let address = subJson["Property"]["Address"].stringValue
                    let coordinates = subJson["Geometry"]["Coordinates"].stringValue
                    let coordinatesArray = coordinates.split(separator: ",")
                    let lat = coordinatesArray[1]
                    let lon = coordinatesArray[0]
                    let latDouble = Double(lat)
                    let lonDouble = Double(lon)

                    let marker = GMSMarker()
                    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latDouble, longitude: lonDouble)
                    marker.title = name
                    marker.snippet = "東京都港区六本木７丁目４−１"
                    marker.map = mapView
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージが示しているように`response.result`は`Result<Any, AFError>`型であり、`Result`型には`value`と言うプロパティがないためエラーになっています。

従って、例えば次のようなコードならコンパイルが通るかと思うのですが、いかがでしょうか?

```
            if let jsonObject = response.result.value {
```

↓

```
            if case .success(let jsonObject) = response.result {
```

(`Result`型から成功時の値を取り出す標準的なやり方。)

[最新のソース](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ResponseSerialization.swift)を見る限り`responseJSON`メソッド用の完了ハンドラは`AFDownloadResponse<Any>`を受け取るようになっており、[`AFDownloadResponse`型には`value`と言うプロパティが存在](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Response.swift)します。そちらを使ってもいいのですが、今後Swift用のライブラリでは`Result`型は多用されるでしょうから、慣れておいた方が良いでしょう。

私自身はAlamofireなんてものは使ったことがないのですが、バージョンによりコロコロとAPIの使い方が変わっていっているようです。ご自身が使用するバージョンにあったコード例を見つけるようにしてください。

またSwiftyJSONは、(少なくとも英語版stackoverflowでは)「古臭いので使わない方が良い」と言う人も多いです。ご質問のようなデータを扱うなら、`Codable`の活用も考えられた方が良いでしょう。